# How can I alternate between a background color and a background image on canvas?

Tags: javascript, css, webgl

I have this program where I can add lights to my scene (stored in an array `lights`). When I first start the program, I want everything to be black since I start with my array empty. But when there is a light, I want to change the background to an image, and when there are no lights, I want everything to be black again.
I´m trying to call this in my render function:

```
if(lights.length == 0) {
  canvas.style.background = "#000000 none";
} else {
  canvas.style.background = "transparent url('nebula.png')";
}
```

But it's not wroking as I intended. Does someone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score -1):

don't use background properties on canvas.
Use `context.fillRect()` to set background color
Use `context.fillImage()` to set background image
Reference:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/fillRect <= fillRect()
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage <= fillImage()

Edit:
Example:

```
const cvs = document.getElementById(' /* your canvas */ ')
const context = cvs.getContext('2d')
// context is the CanvasRenderingContext2D
// use the two commands above to make background.
```

Comment: Is it considered bad progamming to use background properties on canvas?

Comment: Why? I think not, as you are just painting the whole canvas to a color or make an image?

Comment: It is completely different thing, as this uses 2d context. It will just cover the whole thing like a blanket. You will need to draw the things covered again though.

Comment: I'm also creating objects with my context, would this methos change their appearance too, or just the background? Also, I can't seem to find those functions nor create a context. I already do ```gl = setupWebGL(canvas)``` which sets up a webgl context. But I also can't find those functions when calling them through ```gl.```

Comment: No, it is different thing. You don't call these functions with webGl, but with `CanvasRenderingContext2D` @Kob

Comment: It is not the same as webGl. webGl is a graphic library. CanvasRenderingContext2D is used on canvas to draw basic shape, such as rectangles or arcs. 
[tutorial on context 2d](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_canvas.asp)

Comment: @ChengAdrian You shouldn't use `CanvasRenderingContext2D` together with WebGL.

Comment: "*It will just cover the whole thing like a blanket.*" - why? The OP wants a partially transparent canvas content.

Comment: @Bergi  Yes, exactly. I just want to meddle with my background in a way that everything is black when there are no lights, but the background shows when there are lights. And blackens itself out again when I remove the lights. Not looking to add libraries.

Comment: ok, maybe you can add another div element? You can position it onto the canvas and add background properties to the div element? Will this work better? @Kob

Comment: Okay, can you point me somewhere I can learn how to do this?

Comment: Use `position:absolute` on the div element. Then add `top:  insert here  px; left:  insert here  px` to position it.

Comment: Then use `background image, background color, width and height to size it. @Kob